# Problem with .fbx assets after repo clone Unity

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, github, clone, repo

I have a problem with my Unity project and Github repository. Actually my friend pushed and commited branch on his repo, everything worked fine, but when I cloned this repository and switched couple folders into my project, the .fbx files haven't been placed on the map properly but they were recognized by Unity. I'm using LFS. Here I have the .gitattributes file:

```
# 3D models
*.3dm filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.3ds filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.blend filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.c4d filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.collada filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.dae filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.dxf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.fbx filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jas filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.lws filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.lxo filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ma filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.max filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mb filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.obj filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ply filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.skp filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.stl filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ztl filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
# Audio
*.aif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.aiff filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.it filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mod filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.mp3 filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ogg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.s3m filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.wav filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.xm filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
# Fonts
*.otf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ttf filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
# Images
*.bmp filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.exr filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.gif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.hdr filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.iff filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jpeg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.jpg filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.pict filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.png filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.psd filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tga filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tif filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.tiff filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
# Collapse Unity-generated files on GitHub
*.asset linguist-generated
*.mat linguist-generated
*.meta linguist-generated
*.prefab linguist-generated
*.unity linguist-generated
*.aar filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Comment: We can't say why it doesn't work from a list of git attributes. To really say what's wrong we'd have to inspect your git repository and your project. Did your friend use gitlfs? If he didn't have it installed it wouldn't have worked.

Comment: We both have installed LFS. We tried to insert couple of weird commands from internet (which didn't work ofc). So we reinstalled our LFS and it still doesn't work. This problem is only occuring on my PC. And yes, I've installed Blender, but it didn't work too. And you mean that I have to show you our github repo and project? (idk how maybe some screens). Thank you for help